# c3.js - Execute only after c3 has generated data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c3.js

I am generating c3 charts, during the time it is painting the charts, I need to show a waiting icon.

Presently, the icon is implemented with some random timeout due to which the waiting icon disappears, and c3 charts is still not rendered.

I want to keep that waiting icon spinning, and should disappear only after the c3 charts have been rendered. Not sure how to do it.

Comment: Can you some code add code you have done?

Comment: @Sarjan Desai - There is a lot of code, not sure what all to paste. my question is the gist of the problem i am facing.

Comment: Only relevent code.. No need to add all code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the following snippet

```js
$.blockUI()

setTimeout(function () {
    var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    },
      onrendered: function(){ //after chart is rendered
        $.unblockUI();
      }
});
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.js"></script>

<div id="chart"><img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />Waiting..</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [onrendered](https://c3js.org/reference.html#onrendered) function to hide your busy icon.
this would also add a flavor of animation to your charts

For Example:

```
onrendered: function() {
    d3.selectAll(".c3-axis.c3-axis-x .tick text")
        .style("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: Please provide source code example to your answer. Otherwise, This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question.